# How do I get started porting a Windows 8 app to Windows Phone 8?

Tags: windows-8, windows-phone-8

There are some documents to port application from Windows Phone 7 to Windows 8. I need the opposite but Windows Phone 8.

Are there any helper documents to easily port my Windows 8 app to Windows Phone 8?

Answer (score 4):

May be this articles will be helpful:
[Windows Phone 8 and Windows 8 platform comparison](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj681690%28v=vs.105%29.aspx)
[Maximize code reuse between Windows Phone 8 and Windows 8](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj681693%28v=vs.105%29.aspx)

Answer (score 3):

Well it depends.

There are couple of demo video's from Build. They go over code sharing and portability between WinRT and Windows Phone 8.

The general idea is that you should extract your application logic to a `Portable Class Library`. Than your Windows 8/WinRT and Windows Phone 8 apps can share the same application logic and have their separate UI.

Of course this doesn't work in all cases as some of the api's are not cross compatible. But for general cases it should work just fine.

Watch build video's, you'll find lot's of help

http://channel9.msdn.com/home